# what does parameterIndex mean in this syntax pst.setString(parameterIndex, x);?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a code as follow:

```
String query = "select * from EmployerData where userName = ? and password = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, textField.getText());   // what 1 refers to
pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());  // 2
```

which is working perfectly as I want but I get confused about the meaning of parameterIndex. What does parameterIndex mean???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells the query which question mark to replace. The first question mark - index 1. The second question mark - index 2.